# Efficient calculation of potential energy of $n$-body system

Tags: newtonian-gravity, potential, potential-energy, coulombs-law, many-body

Consider $n$ bodies which interact solely through Newtonian gravity/Coulomb force, then the total potential energy of the system can be obtained as:
$$U =\pm \sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}\frac{G\alpha_i\alpha_j}{\left| \mathbf{r}_i - \mathbf{r}_j\right|},$$ where $\alpha$ represents the mass/charge.

The problem is that I am working with a simulation where there are a large number of particles, then calculating this for all pairs is not feasible. I want to calculate the potential energy of my simulation to test that energy is being conserved appropriately.

I do have the total potential field $\phi$. If I calculate
$$E = \sum_i \phi \alpha_i$$
how would this relate o the actual energy
$$U = \sum_i \phi_i \alpha_i$$
where $\phi_i$ is the potential obtained with all particles except the $i^{th}$ one.

Or how could I compute the total potential energy otherwise?

Comment: Would it be reasonable to find the center of mass of the system, and then find every particle's potential with respect to that? I'm not sure how to rigorously show that'd get you the same result, but it seems like it'd work intuitively.

Comment: How many particles do you plan to have? In any case, answer changes as a function  of the system you plan to simulate. Galaxies need a different treatment than crystalline NaCl .

Comment: @GiorgioP Under these assumptions, what differences are needed between newtonian gravity or coulomb interaction? I am actually simulating an electron plasma.

Comment: @NuclearWang Wouldn't that just be the same $E$ I have above? To get $U$ you would need the centre of mass of all particles except the $i^{th}$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: An electron plasma under which kind of conditions? (equilibrium, non equilibrium, I presume non-degenerate, else?)

Comment: @GiorgioP I fail to see how any of these restrictions have any impact on the numerical calculation I want to perform. I can load in my simulation a single electron, or $10^6$ charged particles both in equilibrium or non equilibrium. The underlying problem is to calculate the potential energy of n bodies.

Comment: It happens that there are different methods and each of them is optimized for specific  cases. You may  search on google for  "Ewald method" or "N-body tree methods" to have a vague idea  of the huge variety of methods. And no web page will tell you which is the best for your case. If you like to have a useful answer it is better to explain what is your typical system.

Comment: You say you have $\phi(x)$ - how are you computing this? It might be simple to subtract off the self contribution, or your approximation scheme to find $\phi$ might already be such that doing so makes no sense and you should just use your $E$ integral. It's hard to say without details.

Comment: Perhaps Computational Science SE would be a better place for this question because it is more about finding an efficient algorithm than about eg explaining how to calculate potential energy or what it means.